# Which variations of the flash ADC is correct?

Tags: analog, adc, measurement, voltage-measurement, converter

The flash ADC I learnt in class is this one with R all of the same value:

[image: R]

I found different variations on the internet:

This one has the top resistor with 3 times the value of other resistors.

[image: 3R]

This one has the top comparator connected directly to Vref(one less resistor).

[image: 2^N-1 R]

This one has the top and bottom resistors half the value of all other resistors.

[image: R/2]

Which one is correct? I have a feeling that they are all correct.  If that is the case, in what situations are a specific variation (variations of the resistor ladders only) preferred over another? What are the limitations of each?

I've been taught that a flash ADC has 2^N resistors, but since one of the variations has 1 less resistor, is 2^N resistors actually not true or does not always have to be the case?

Answer (score 2):

They are all correct. In all cases, the ladder of resistors is the same, giving uniform steps.

Where they differ is what happens precisely at the ends. Maybe the comparators don't have common mode voltage all the way to the top rail, so the 3x resistor is used to drop that voltage into range. Maybe they have been designed to get a specific relationship between GND, Vref, and exactly when the code changes (bottom of the step, mid-way through the step).

Answer (score 1):

They are all correct.

The only difference is what ends up being the range and threshold between the steps.

Which again depends on what you want to sample and why.

In some case you might want to just always truncate down. In some case you might want to round to nearest value.